# Django Warning regex beginning with a '/' when running a server

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-urls

**When I run a server in console I am getting warnings:**

```
?: (urls.W002) Your URL pattern '^/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$' [name='detail'] has a regex beginning with a '/'. Remove this slash as it is unnecessary.
```

I did some research and found that you can silence checks with the `SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS` setting.

In *urls.py* url patterns are defined as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', PostListAPIView.as_view(), name='list'),
    url(r'^/create/$', PostCreateAPIView.as_view(), name='create'),
    url(r'^/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', PostDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$',
        PostUpdateAPIView.as_view(), name='update'),
    url(r'^/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/delete/$',
        PostDeleteAPIView.as_view(), name='delete'),
```

When '/' is removed after `"r'^"` I have an error from server: `Page Not Found (404)` error, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
....

When '/' is added it is working perfectly. 
But I guess there should other workarounds to fix this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: As the warning says, you shouldn't start a url with a slash. Show an example of the page you try to visit and get 404 when you remove the slash

Comment: @Furkat Gafurov can you show us all urls conf of your project?

Comment: @JPG I went back to urls conf of my project and found out '/' was missing in url patterns after api/posts. After correction:
   " urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^api/posts/', include("posts.api.urls", namespace='posts-api'))
      ] " ,
it works just fine.